# Check if my leadfeeder is working

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I have an angular application where i am using `prerender` to index my site.

Since i started this (about a week ago) my leadfeeder has not been able to find any leads.

I find this odd because my `google analytics` shows that people are on my site.

So my question is how can i check that my `leadfeeder` is working correctly? Could `prerender` have any effect on `leadfeeder` or is this just a very odd coincidence ?